# Can't get python script to pick up all terms in text search list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a python 3 script that will search the user-defined folder for certain search terms and 1. copy files with matching words to a new folder on the desktop and 2. create a text file that contains the matched search terms.

The script is working, but for whatever reason, it seems to be maxing out with 1-2 search terms added to the "search_text_list". For example, in the example below, I only get matches for "Displayed" and "x exception". However, when I modify the list to just have "ERR:", it will pick it up, where it would miss it in my longer list of search terms.

I'm very new to python/coding, but anyone have an idea of what might be going on?

CODE

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime

source_folder = input("Enter the source folder path: ")
search_text_list = ["x exception", "Displayed", "!!!!!", "thermal event", "ERR:", "WRN", "InstrumentMonitorEvent"]
target_folder_name = "NovaSeq 6000 Parsing"
match_file_folder_name = "NovaSeq 6000 Analyzer Output_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S"))
match_file_info = "Matched Search Terms.txt"
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
target_folder = os.path.join(desktop, target_folder_name)
match_file_folder = os.path.join(target_folder, match_file_folder_name)
match_file_path = os.path.join(match_file_folder, match_file_info)

if not os.path.exists(target_folder):
    os.makedirs(target_folder)

if not os.path.exists(match_file_folder):
    os.makedirs(match_file_folder)

#Find all the matched search terms defined in the Search_text_list and copy them to the folder as well as make a text file with the matched fw
matched_search_terms = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
    if "ETF" in dirs:
        dirs.remove("ETF")
    for file in files:
        if "Warnings_And_Errors" in file:
            continue
        if "RunSetup" in file:
            continue
        if "Wash" in file:
            continue
        full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        with open(full_path, 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
            file_content = f.read().lower()
            for search_text in search_text_list:
                if search_text.lower() in file_content:
                    matched_search_terms.append(search_text)
                    shutil.copy2(full_path, match_file_folder)
                    break

with open(match_file_path, 'w') as f:
    if len(matched_search_terms) > 0:
        f.write("\n".join(matched_search_terms))
    else:
        f.write("NA")
```

I have confirmed that my search text list works, but there seems to be a limit on the number of terms I can add to my list that will match sucessfully.

Comment: What's the point of `dirs.remove("ETF")`? You never use the `dirs` list for anything.

Comment: If a file matches multple search terms, only the first one will be put into `matched_search_terms`. Is that the problem? I suspect all the files with `ERR:` also have one of the earlier search words, so you never get that into the list.

Answer (score 0):

You only get the first matching search term for each file, because you break out of the loop after the first match.

Instead of a loop, use a list comprehension to get all the matches, then add that to the list.

```
        with open(full_path, 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
            file_content = f.read().lower()
            matching_terms = [term for term in search_text_list if term.lower() in file_content]
            if matching_terms:
                matched_seach_terms.extend(matching_terms)
                shutil.copy2(full_path, match_file_folder)
```

You might also want to make `matched_search_terms` a set rather than a list, so you don't get lots of duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, Barmar! This is working to match more terms, but for whatever reason, it is now missing files that it was previously catching. Looking at the match file folder, I'm only getting 1 file that matches now, where I used to get 9 files matching.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code that is only matching 1 file now. I'm now matching Displayed, WRN, InstrumentMonitorEvent, which I was previously missing.

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime

source_folder = input("Enter the source folder path: ")
search_text_list = ["x exception", "Displayed", "!!!!!", "thermal event", "ERR:", "WRN", "InstrumentMonitorEvent"]
target_folder_name = "NovaSeq 6000 Parsing"
match_file_folder_name = "NovaSeq 6000 Analyzer Output_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S"))
match_file_info = "Matched Search Terms.txt"
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
target_folder = os.path.join(desktop, target_folder_name)
match_file_folder = os.path.join(target_folder, match_file_folder_name)
match_file_path = os.path.join(match_file_folder, match_file_info)

if not os.path.exists(target_folder):
    os.makedirs(target_folder)

if not os.path.exists(match_file_folder):
    os.makedirs(match_file_folder)

#Find all the matched search terms defined in the Search_text_list and copy them to the folder as well as make a text file with the matched fw
matched_search_terms = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
    for file in files:
        if "Warnings_And_Errors" in file:
            continue
        if "RunSetup" in file:
            continue
        if "Wash" in file:
            continue
        full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        with open(full_path, 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
            file_content = f.read().lower()
            matching_terms = [term for term in search_text_list if term.lower() in file_content]
            if matching_terms:
                matched_search_terms.extend(matching_terms)
                shutil.copy2(full_path, match_file_folder)
                break

with open(match_file_path, 'w') as f:
    if len(matched_search_terms) > 0:
        f.write("\n".join(matched_search_terms))
    else:
        f.write("NA")
```